# g++ multiple definition of `_init'

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++

Simplest program ever has g++ link errors. Searched everywhere.

```
$ /usr/bin/g++ --version

    g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)

    Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

$ cat /etc/redhat-release

    CentOS release 5.11 (Final)
```

----- a.cpp -----

```
int main()
{
}
```

---

Note: I know that I don't have to specify a -o option as it will default to a.out, so what the heck is going on here. I have done this dozens of times on other machines.

```
$ /usr/bin/g++ a.cpp
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crti.o: In function `_init':

(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crti.o: In function `_fini':

(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/crtbegin.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here

/tmp/ccYgVWiH.o: In function `main':

a.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.text+0xa8): first defined here

/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `main' changed from 18 in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o to 11 in /tmp/ccYgVWiH.o

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/crtend.o:(.dtors+0x0): multiple definition of `__DTOR_END__'

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.dtors+0x8): first defined here

/usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400430
```

---

Note: This works under OS:
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.1 (Tikanga)
But not in my:
CentOS release 5.11 (Final)

Note: This works just fine but I need it w/o the -m32

```
/usr/bin/g++ -m32 a.cpp
```

Comment: This is very likely a broken installation of GCC/binutils. Can you `g++ -c` compile only the file?

Comment: Yes, and it generates an a.o

Comment: Funny thing is /usr/bin/g++ -m32 a.cpp works just fine.

Comment: There's something wrong with either your CentOS install, or your GCC install. This might be a good time to upgrade to something less than 9 years old.